# Failed to read part of the files from s3 bucket with Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a Spark 2.4.7 running on GCP Dataproc and task to read some files from AWS S3.

Having AWS credentials, namely access key and secret access key, appended to files /etc/profile.d/spark_config.sh /etc/*bashrc /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh at cluster creation, I can read **SOME** of the files from my S3 bucket, while reading all of them gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 274, in json
    return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o202.json.
: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: s3a://my_bucket/part-00000-a5adf948-1f65-4068-ae68-76c3708b4cf1-c000.txt.lzo: getFileStatus on s3a://my_bucket/part-00000-a5adf948-1f65-4068-ae68-76c3708b4cf1-c000.txt.lzo: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: Q3TR40YDDCWFKESZ; S3 Extended Request ID: MeZc+rmfDXDL2DEXWS8zpfrn1s3dbthI31pErLpVT14kTGjpaxUYEmBG53D9f1cWwVRVL1oCzeM=), S3 Extended Request ID: MeZc+rmfDXDL2DEXWS8zpfrn1s3dbthI31pErLpVT14kTGjpaxUYEmBG53D9f1cWwVRVL1oCzeM=
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1923)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1877)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1632)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.exists(S3AFileSystem.java:2631)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1(DataSource.scala:575)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:242)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:411)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code I use for reading:

```
spark.read \
 .option("io.compression.codecs", "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec") \
 .schema(StructType().add("id", StringType())) \
 .json("s3a://my_bucket/*.lzo")
```

Files in the location are inserted at different times using the same mechanism. Examining one of the "corrupted" files using AWS CLI, I see the error:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/part-00000-499c7394-c5cf-4045-8a54-0e1d5bc87897-c000.txt.lzo - | head
download failed: s3://my_bucket/part-00000-499c7394-c5cf-4045-8a54-0e1d5bc87897-c000.txt.lzo to - An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

My question is how to further trace down the failed reads of some of the files. Thank you!

**UPD:**

Somehow the problematic files are ununsually small compared to the rest: ~4KiB in size compared to 30-50MiB other items.

Comment: It looks like you might be facing a permissions issue based on your CLI 403 forbidden - you should check your user's IAM role policies regarding S3 as well as the specific bucket policy for that bucket. As for the EMR Spark job failing-  try to change s3a:// to s3:// and confirm the EMR cluster has access to that bucket along with the objects inside it.

Comment: The thing is - I am able to read (both with Spark and AWS CLI) some of the files in the VERY SAME location

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the objects that aren't readable aren't [KMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingKMSEncryption.html) encrypted ? Have you also taken a look at the bucket policies etc..?

Comment: No encryption is used. If this was a policies issue - could I read other files..

Comment: 403 == caller lacks the permission to HEAD the file or decrypt. As bobshark says -make sure there's no default bucket encryption and the client has permissions.
One more thing: don't use the root directory as a destination of work, it's "special". Try putting everything into a subdir and working there.